# Is there any way to change the tab spacing in the MarkLogic Query Console?

Tags: marklogic

The standard tab spacing for query console is set to 2 spaces.  Is there any way to adjust this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is an exposed way to override it, but the indentation is configured in: `/MarkLogic/Apps/common/codemirror5/lib/codemirror.js`

On line 5364:

```
option("indentUnit", 2, loadMode, true);
```

You could hack on that file in your install to adjust the indent. However, if you upgrade or re-install your changes will be lost.

Some editor options have recently been exposed and allowed to be configured to control code completion, intelli-sense, etc. You might file a Support ticket requesting that the code indent be added as another option for users to control the behavior of the Query Console editor.

Comment: It is possible to affect the desired change in a slightly less intrusive way way that leaves the ML codebase intact. (1) make a new Modules directory for yourself on the filesystem. (2) copy the codemirror.js to the new dir (3) copy the 8000-rewriter.xml here and point to it. (4) modify the rewriter by placing a new rule at the top pointing to your local copy of the codemirror.js file. Now you can modify as much as you wish.  Note: for these items(usually when testing a new release) I have my modules dir outside of the ML dir and symlink - keeping it an arm's length from the installed files.

Comment: I wish modules took precedence over the filesystem instead of the other way around. Then it would be much easier to insert a patched module and it would survive re-install.

Comment: Agreed. Especially for a clustered solution, you would expect the database to be priority since it offers a consistent storage location.  Items as described above only take affect on the host being executed :(